# Detecting When An Apple Music Song Has Finished Playing

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm writing an app that needs to enact an action when a song has finished playing. I'm using MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer() as my music player to play the user's apple music. I was wondering if there was a way I could detect when a users song has finished playing or when the queue has finished (either would be helpful)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MPMusicPlayerController` has an instance method [`beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624199-begingeneratingplaybacknotificat). There are three `Notification`s that will be delivered to subscribers:

1. `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange`
2. `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange`
3. `MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChange`

To detect when playing a song or a queue has finished, you can use `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange`.

When you receive that notification, check the `MPMusicPlayerController`s `nowPlayingItem` (see [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624245-nowplayingitem)). If the song finished and another one is played `nowPlayingItem` will have changed. If the whole queue finished and there is nothing playing, `nowPlayingItem` will have a value `nil`.

Comment: Hello! 
I know it is an old answer but I want to ask something about MPMusicPlayer.

Is MPMusicPlayer can control when music listening from the apple music app?

Actually, I want to learn; is MPMusicPlayerController only using the device's Music app library or it can also have the capability to use and control Apple music?